# Accessing design time controls from a separate design-time form

Tags: c#, forms, controls, design-time

I am looking for the ***easiest*** way to access the design-time controls created in the main form of a windows application form from another form.  I am going to want to manipulate all the controls and would prefer not to make getter and setter methods. There will only ever be a couple of additional forms that are only used for input in order to change the states of controls on the primary form--so I am not concerned about best practices here because this is not going to be a big project where many people are going to be working and multiple variables are going to get confused, and because I am completely new to this and want something that works. I am not working in a professional programming environment.

I would like to be able to simply address them with dot syntax somehow.

That said: Merely changing the type to "public" doesn't seem to allow me to do this however.

So, for a textbox, when I change it from:

```
private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox AssignmentSectNumber;
```

To

```
public System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox AssignmentSectNumber;
```

Where the C# system automatically declares it once I put it into my form, I still can not access it from form two with

```
Form1.AssignmentSectNumber.Text
```

Is there any way that I can set up the controls in `Form1` so that they can be addressed in `Form2` either by going through `Form1` through dot syntax or simply by directly addressing them?

PS: I do not see a way to make controls "public" under any of the properties listed when I put them into a form at design time.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Its difficult to say what you are trying to do here. `Form1.AssignmentSectNumber` will give an error because `AssignmentSectNumber` is an instance property, not static. You can't change the design of a form at runtime because after the form loads and the `InitializeComponent` call is made, the form will be reset to defaults. I think the best option is to construct the entire form programmatically, but this is a giant PIA, aka `Form newForm = new Form(); newForm.Controls.Add(new SomeControl());`... For all your controls and settings.

Comment: This really isn't an option for me.  The forms are completely designed.  This took a great deal of effort.

Are you saying that if I make two forms in design mode, and form 1 has a textbox that there is no way for code that is part of form 2 to change the text in the textbox of form1?  All controls in form1 must forever be isolated from form2 unless I create them in-program?

Comment: You can modify it,  but you have to modify an *instance* of it, i.e. `Form2 frm2 =new Form2(); frm2.AssignmentSelector.Text ="some value";` You can't operate on the type itself,  you have to do it on instances. This also means that the controls on the forum need to be set to public.

Comment: This is probably a silly question, but remember that I am new at this.

When I run the program form1 appears on the screen.  Doesn't this mean that there must be an instance of it?  If the name of that intance isn't form1 what would it be?

Comment: Look in your Program.cs file,  you'll see a line like `Application.Run(new Form1());`. That is the instance of your Form being created,  it doesn't get stored in a variable but it can be changed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not see a way to make controls "public" under any of the
>   properties listed when I put them into a form at design time. Am I
>   missing something?

Select the Control and then in the Properties Pane, change its Modifiers Property to Public.

> When I run the program form1 appears on the screen. Doesn't this mean
>   that there must be an instance of it? If the name of that intance
>   isn't form1 what would it be?

You need to access the currently running instance of Form1.  There are many ways to do this.  One very simple method is to set the Owner of the secondary form when you call its Show() method:

```
// ... from within Form1 ...
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Show(this); // <-- setting Form1 as the "owner" of Form2 via "this"
```

Now, over in Form2, you cast the .Owner property back to Form1 and access the Control(s) you changed the Modifiers Property for to Public:

```
// ... over in Form2 ...
Form1 f1 = (Form1)this.Owner;
f1.label1.Text = "Hello from Form2!";
```

Comment: Thanks!  Haven't tried it yet, but this looks like just what I need.  I had been trying to get around the problem by having an additional form spawn all the others--it was a big mess.